# Google Script - Create Events to Multiple Calendars

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a spreadsheet with a list of events, but need to insert them into their own respective calendars. So far I have this:

```
function pushCalendars() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i in sheets){
    if (sheets.length >  1){
    var lastRow = sheets[i].getLastRow();
    var range = sheets[i].getRange(3,1,lastRow,100);
    var data = range.getValues();
    for (i in data){
      var row = data[i];
      var title = row[0];
      var title2 = row[1];
      var date = row[2];
      var desc = row[3];
      var calName = ss.getSheetByName("Resorts").getRange('E3').getValue();
      var cal = CalendarApp.openByName(calName);
      cal.createAllDayEvent(title,date);
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any solutions!

Answer (score 0):

If the calendars are owned by your user you will face no problems. 
The only thing that you need to change in your code is to create the calendars that still does not exists with this piece of code:

```
// Creates a new calendar named "Travel Plans" with a summary and color.
 var calendar = CalendarApp.createCalendar('Travel Plans', {
  summary: 'A calendar to plan my travel schedule.',
   color: CalendarApp.Color.BLUE
 });
 Logger.log('Created the calendar "%s", with the ID "%s".',
     calendar.getName(), calendar.getId());
```

The API documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app?hl=pt-BR#createCalendar%28String,Object%29).

If the calendars belongs to other user you will need to have administrative permissions to modify it and you need to log with OAuth plus calling the calendar API using URLFetch (Calendar API can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I already have the calendars created, so I'd need to get them by name which where I'm running into trouble.

Comment: What trouble are you facing?

Comment: I want to be able to create new sheets & have the function run on those, without having to go back within the code & add the calendar or sheet to the code. I don't exactly know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I always get my calendars by id, since the calendars already exist, you could get the calendar ID from the Calendar Settings, and insert them into the script as Project Properties. Then all you need to do is load the id that matches the name.

Change these two lines:

```
var calName = ss.getSheetByName("Resorts").getRange('E3').getValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.openByName(calName);
```

To this:

```
var calName = ss.getSheetByName("Resorts").getRange('E3').getValue();
var calID = ScriptProperties.getProperty(calName);
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarByID(calID);
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#scriptProperties for reference on ScriptProperties.

Comment: So this? function pushCalendars(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheets();
  for (i in sheet){
    if (sheet.length>1){
      var lastRow=sheet[i].getLastRow();
      var range=sheet[i].getRange(3,1,lastRow,100);
      var data=range.getValues();
  for (i in data){
  var row=data[i];
  var title=row[0];
  var date=row[2];
  var desc=row[3];
  var calName=sheet[i].getRange('E3').getValue();
  var calId=ScriptProperties.getProperty(calName);
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
          var newEvent=cal[i].createAllDayEvent(title,date); }}}}

Comment: So I tried that and I got back "Type Error: Cannot call method "createAllDayEvent" of null."

Comment: Did you create the Script properties with the calendar IDs matched to the Calendar names?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite sure why this script is being so difficult. It the CalName addition has worked when I am working in just one sheet, but when I try to run it through multiple sheets.

Comment: Found it. With all the code crammed into the comments I had some trouble reading it. newEvent=cal[i].createAllDayEvent(title, date); but cal is not an array, so cal[i] returns null.